# display inline not working for divs containing text

Tags: html, css, inline

I'm creating a style sheet for use on mobiles and the text needs to be condensed down into one column, rather that the two that are displayed side by side on a desktop.

I'm wondering whether my issue has anything to doing the positioning that I have applied to the divs?

Please see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vtdo8vc0/

```css
#col1 {
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  width: 94%;
  padding-right: 3%;
  padding-left: 3%;
}
#col2 {
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  width: 94%;
  padding-right: 3%;
  padding-left: 3%;
}
.col {
  font-family: 'Avenir-Book';
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 16px;
  font-weight: 500;
}
#main_content {
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
#main_content img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}
#header {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 3%;
  padding-left: 3%;
  padding-right: 3%;
  padding-bottom: 3%;
}
.header {
  font-family: 'Avenir-Book';
  font-size: 26px;
  line-height: 26px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 900;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="header">
    <div class="header">
      food
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="col1">
    <div class="col">
      At Danny’s we believe food is very important! Kevin our Head Chef has a wealth of experience and a passion to rival that experience. Wherever possible our food is created using the very best locally sourced ingredients. Whether you are
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="col2">
    <div class="col">
      popping in for a lunchtime wrap or a full blown Danny's Burger you can expect the same level of service and attention to detail.
      <br>
      <br>Check out our menu below.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="main_content">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What exactly is the issue?

Comment: On iPhone, it's one column. What's the problem?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I would like the text to interlock and run seamlessly as if it was all inside one div, instead of just being in one column but sitting one on top of the other with a gap

Comment: @ckuijjer I would like the text to interlock and run seamlessly as if it was all inside one div, instead of just being in one column but sitting one on top of the other with a gap

Comment: I'm afraid you won't be able to do this with good browser support (IE10+ and vendor prefixes). Using two separate `<div>`'s will never properly work if you think about font resizing or slightly different font rendering. Best thing might be to read up on css columns, see https://css-tricks.com/guide-responsive-friendly-css-columns/ as a start

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want the two columns to behave like they're ons wall of text, at least on narrower screens. Then the solution would be to make #col1, #col2 and .col inline and dispense with the floats.

```css
#col1,
#col2 {
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
}
.col {
  display: inline;
  font: 500 12px/16px'Avenir-Book', sans-serif;
}
#main_content {
  padding: 0 10px 10px 10px;
}
#main_content img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}
#header {
  position: relative;
  padding: 3%;
}
.header {
  font: 900 26px/26px'Avenir-Book', sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
@media all and (min-width: 50em) {
  /* change into 2 columns on wider screens */
  #col1,
  #col2 {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 47%;
    padding: 0 3%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="header">
    <div class="header">
      food
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="col1">
    <div class="col">
      At Danny’s we believe food is very important! Kevin our Head Chef has a wealth of experience and a passion to rival that experience. Wherever possible our food is created using the very best locally sourced ingredients. Whether you are
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="col2">
    <div class="col">
      popping in for a lunchtime wrap or a full blown Danny's Burger you can expect the same level of service and attention to detail.
      <br>
      <br>Check out our menu below.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="main_content">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
  </div>
</div>
```